# Instantiating Backbone by trigger? (Or How to defer execution of an anonymous function?)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, instantiation

Continuing my quest to learn more about Backbone.js I have arrived to a situation where I would want to instantiate a Backbone application programmatically. This occurs in a situation where the entire site/page is not a Backbone application, but instead a modal is opened, then populated (base structure for Backbone app), and *then* I would like to trigger the Backbone application (whose JavaScript was also loaded when the modal was opened). I would prefer to instantiate the Backbone app 'manually' if possible, i.e. so that it would not auto-execute when its script is loaded.

The typical Backbone format I have been using is like this:

```
var myApp = (function($) {

    var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        ...
    });

    var modelInstance = new myModel({
        ...
    });        

    var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
        ...
    });

    var viewInstance = new myView({
        ...
    });

}
```

But the above is automatically executed when the script file is loaded, then the instantiated view(s) attempt to bind/render to their associated DOM elements, etc. Is there a way to defer the execution of the anonymous function so that I could load the script when the modal is being prepared but then trigger the Backbone app on command at a [slightly] later point?

Many thanks for any insights on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put your app's components into an object with an `init` method, which you can then call when your modal dialog opens. Here's an example structure:

```
window.App = {
  Models: {},
  Views: {},
  Routers: {},
  init: function () {
    var app = new window.App.Routers.main;
    Backbone.History.start();
    return app;
  }
};

window.App.Models.Foo = Backbone.Model.extend({
  // ...
});

window.App.Views.FooView = Backbone.View.extend({
  // ...
});

window.App.Routers.main = Backbone.Router.extend({
  // ...
});

window.modalDialog.onOpen = function () {
  window.app = window.App.init();
};
```

The above assumes you have a global variable called `modalDialog`representing your modal window, which calls its `onOpen` callback when the window is shown.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've been playing with some ideas derived from your example and I believe it will work. Here's a follow-up question: why does window.app.init return an instance of window.App.Routers.main? Is that an arbitrary choice (as opposed to being an instance of, say, window.App.Models.Foo)?

Comment: It doesn't have to be. A lot of apps initialize by instantiating a router and starting the history, but it could be started in just about any way. The other most likely choice would be instantiating a view.

Comment: Does this method play well with require.js? I have a similar solution and am trying to declare it in a module and it's barking